# i need solution for brute force 6 digit otp,

Tags: http, testing, server, brute-force, exploit

suppose I need to implement a system to brute force a 6-digit OTP. I have 100 Core 2 Duo computers. Each computer has 1/2gb ram and a 20mbps Broadband connection, but OTPs expire within 300 seconds or 5 minutes. Now how can I successfully get OTP with that setup?

I wrote Python code for sending HTTP requests with multiprocessing with 200 threads

request size: suppose 1kb
response size: suppose 1kb

from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

with Pool(200) as speed:

I need to solve this problem. I am working on HackerOne as a bug bounty hunter/pentester.

Answer (score -1):

You need to `import itertools`
And then you can loop through all possible combinations.

```
    for otp in map(''.join, itertools.product("0123456789", repeat=6)):
        print(otp)
```

`otp` is the current combination and you can change the first argument of `itertools.product` to change the digits/characters and their order or change `repeat` to get a different length.

Comment: you are not understand my Question bro.. read all text

Comment: @ShafkatRaihan You wrote the code for the HTTP request already, got some code for bruteforceing the otp now you only need to combine this and add some multiprocessing. You should be able to find a few good resources regarding Multiprocessing using Google. If you want to have success on HackerOne you should use this opportunity to train your Python-Skills. If you encounter any problems, I'd be glad to help, but I (and probably most users here as well) wont do all the work for you.

Comment: i am not talking about code. i am talking about implementation for brute force, i am very expert in python . 8 years+ experience . if possible tell me. how can i done my setup. with 100 computer . will it work perfect . or failed. i never want waste money

Comment: @ShafkatRaihan Oh, so you wanted to know whether it's possible or not. If we estimate about 1-2 seconds per request and take 100 computers each running 200 threads, each thread will need to send 50 requests(if OTP consists of 6 digits 0-9) so it would take approximately 50-100 seconds. If I misunderstood and you have 200 threads in total (not for each computer) then it would be possible, if the average time per request is below 58 milliseconds.